# What does で mean here in "危険を承知で声がした方へ向かう 。"

Tags: particles, particle-で

I'm reading くまクマ熊ベアー and I came upon this sentence

> 危険かと思ったが初めての人の声だ。危険を承知**で**声がした方へ向かう。

- Would it be acceptable to say

"危険を承知して声がした方へ向かう。"

- What does the で here mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That で can be understood as indicating attendant circumstances.

> 危険を承知**で**声がした方へ向かう。
> Knowing of the danger, I head towards where the voice comes from.

It could be rephrased as:

> 危険を理解した上で声がした方へ向かう。

It is not very common for 承知 to be immediately followed by the copula (or the particle で) like this. 〜を承知で may be seen as a fixed expression.

[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%89%BF%E7%9F%A5/) has these examples:

> 無理を承知でお願いする。

> 君の言うことなど百も承知だ。

百も承知だ is another fixed expression as it is. It has the implications of “you don’t need to explain.”

危険を承知**して**声がした方へ向かう sounds odd because the verb form 承知する is often used in the sense of “to consent (to)” or “to approve” as in the following example from the same dictionary.

> 申し出の件、確かに承知した。

In the sense of “to know” or “to understand”, it is usually used in the forms of 承知しました and 承知しています／おります mostly in business settings. These are the humble versions of, respectively, わかりました and わかっています.